# How to add values from state to array in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am tring to push new value to arrays but the arrays is not updating with new values. It only contains one value after push. The `arr` value after button click only showing one value, but I want it to have multiple values. What are multiple ways to put values into arr variable or copy value to another variable?

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  let arr = [];

  function addToArr() {
     console.log(value);
     arr.push(value);

     console.log(arr);   // it is only showing one value
  }

  return (
    <div>react app
      <div>
          <textarea
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          >
          </textarea>

        <button onClick={addToArr}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for this, or state if you need the UI to update when `arr` is updated.

Comment: @NickParsons, apologies if this is a rather dumb question: how could one use `ref` in this context? I understand using a state variable to hold `arr` will do the trick; but, couldn't quite figure-out (for myself) how `ref` would help solve.

Comment: @jsN00b It would be something along the lines of `const arr = useRef([])`, and then instead of OP doinng `arr.push(value)` they could use `arr.current.push(value)` :)

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks, It works. If I want to assign it a new variable like this `let copyValue = value`, then what will be correct approach.

Comment: @i_am_learning You can set the value of the ref by updating the `.current` value: `arr.current = value` if that is what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you put `let arr = [];` in the component `App` which will be re-rendered whenever the state changes, your `arr` will be reset as well.

One possible fix could be moving your `arr` declaration out of the component `App`

```
let arr = []; //move it to the global scope
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  function addToArr() {
     console.log(value);
     arr.push(value);

     console.log(arr); 
  }

  return (
    <div>react app
      <div>
          <textarea
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          >
          </textarea>

        <button onClick={addToArr}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

If you want to keep `arr` internally, you can use `useRef` which only refers to the same object during re-renderings

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const arrRef = useRef([]);

  function addToArr() {
     console.log(value);
     arrRef.current.push(value);

     console.log(arrRef.current);  
  }

  return (
    <div>react app
      <div>
          <textarea
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          >
          </textarea>

        <button onClick={addToArr}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have 2 ways:

1. Lifting arr variable before component

```
let arr = [];
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  ...
}
export default App;
```

2. Using a new state

```
function App() {  
  ...
  const [newArrValue, setnewArrValue] = useState([]);

  const addToArr = () => {
    ...    
    newArrValue.push(value);
    setnewArrValue(newArrValue);
    console.log(newArrValue); 
  };
  ...
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the useState, you can try this:

```
var [array, setArray] = useState(["a", "b"]);
const fun = () => {
    setArray((oldArray) => [...oldArray, "c"])
}
fun()
```